# Clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) in project

Tags: xcode

When I try to build my Xcode project this error comes up:

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

It is really frustrating because I cannot get rid of it. It shows up in my normal target and my test target. Please help.

The full error is below thanks.

```
Ld /Users/callumbondy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dotcha!-ajrirvxbqfcklkfaxgrfgwslckom/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Dotcha!.app/Dotcha! normal i386
    cd "/Users/callumbondy/Desktop/Desktop/Projects/Dotcha!"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.2
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.3.sdk -L/Users/callumbondy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dotcha!-ajrirvxbqfcklkfaxgrfgwslckom/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Applications/Adobe\ Flash\ CC\ 2014/AIR13.0/lib/aot/stub -F/Users/callumbondy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dotcha!-ajrirvxbqfcklkfaxgrfgwslckom/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/callumbondy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dotcha!-ajrirvxbqfcklkfaxgrfgwslckom/Build/Intermediates/Dotcha!.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Dotcha!.build/Objects-normal/i386/Dotcha!.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/callumbondy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dotcha!-ajrirvxbqfcklkfaxgrfgwslckom/Build/Intermediates/Dotcha!.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Dotcha!.build/Objects-normal/i386/Dotcha_.swiftmodule -mios-simulator-version-min=8.2 -framework StoreKit -framework iAd -framework GameKit -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/callumbondy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dotcha!-ajrirvxbqfcklkfaxgrfgwslckom/Build/Intermediates/Dotcha!.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Dotcha!.build/Objects-normal/i386/Dotcha!_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/callumbondy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dotcha!-ajrirvxbqfcklkfaxgrfgwslckom/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Dotcha!.app/Dotcha!

ld: warning: ignoring file /Applications/Adobe Flash CC 2014/AIR13.0/lib/aot/stub/libSystem.dylib, file was built for armv7 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /Applications/Adobe Flash CC 2014/AIR13.0/lib/aot/stub/libSystem.dylib
ld: in '/Applications/Adobe Flash CC 2014/AIR13.0/lib/aot/stub/libobjc.A.dylib', file was built for armv7 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /Applications/Adobe Flash CC 2014/AIR13.0/lib/aot/stub/libobjc.A.dylib for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library `libobjc.A.dylib` that you are using don't have an `i386` architecture slice. You probably is getting this error when running the app on simulator right?

Compile using a compatible version of your library or try to run on a real device to see if it resolves your problem.

Comment: I tried running it on my device and one of the errors went away, but I still get the same error in my Testing target.